# Magento 2 - Add a new field in checkout address form js error

Tags: onepage-checkout, shipping-address, magento2.2.2

Magento version: 2.2.2

I need to add a custom field in address form on checkout page. So i did what is described on magento documentation:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html

Everything works ok, but when i complete all informations and press the next button to go to payment methods, an error ocurred in js:

"Cannot read property 'items' of undefined" on Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals.js

[image]

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

This error means item field doesn't exit in you pub/static/.. folder location. 
Try clearing out your pub/static folder containing all js files

run command

```
<magento root directory> rm -rf pub/static/*
```

to remove all static files

```
<magento root directory> bin/magento s:static-content:d -f
```

to re-deploy all your static content.